# SQLAlchemy .contains case insensitive and_ query

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am currently trying to get a query to work as case insensitive.  The query currently works as case sensitive like this:

```
and_(db.data.contains({'collections': [{'idType': id_type, 'InternalId': internal_id}]}))
```

The goal of this is to create N number of search filters to query against the DB.  This one being a check for a certain collection containing the data provided to the function.  When I have tried `ilike` or `func.lower` inside the contains it gives me the error of `keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not Function sqlalchemy` or similar.  There also does not seem to be a .icontains function and all the similar `.filter` stackoverflow questions don't fit with my problem.

My question is:  Can the .contains check the db for values regardless of case. so that querying for

```
{'collections': [{'idType': 'Foo', 'InternalId': 'Bar'}]}
```

would return any DB values with a collection.idType of (Foo, FOO, foo, etc) and a collection.externalId of (Bar, BAR, bar, etc)

Comment: Please note that it helps immensely in forming meaningful answers, if the relevant models are included in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to unnest the array using `json(b)_array_elements` and then use an EXISTS subquery expression. Given a model

```
class Foo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'foo'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    data = Column(JSONB)
```

and

```
session.add(Foo(data={'collections': [{'idType': 'Foo', 'InternalId': 'Bar'}]}))
session.commit()
```

The query would be

```
from sqlalchemy import column, exists, func

cs = func.jsonb_array_elements(Foo.data["collections"]).alias("cs")
id_type = column("cs", type_=JSONB)["idType"].astext
internal_id = column("cs", type_=JSONB)["InternalId"].astext

session.query(Foo).\
    filter(exists().select_from(cs).where(and_(
        func.lower(id_type) == "foo",
        func.lower(internal_id) == "bar"))).\
    all()
```

The same in raw SQL is a bit more easier on the eyes in this case:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(foo.data -> 'collections') cs
    WHERE lower(cs ->> 'idType') = 'foo'
      AND lower(cs ->> 'InternalId') = 'bar'
)
```

Comment: Would this allow multiple queries to be appended with this?  This is one of several `and_` queries added to an overall `or_` query that is executed on the data.

Comment: I don't see why not.

Comment: Ok I will try this and see if it will.  Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Does not solve the specific case described but I will answer the generic question: You can use `contains` after `sa.func.lower`.

```py
search = session.query(models.YourModel)
for keyword in keywords:  # Create a filter for each keyword (like and_)
    search = search.filter(
        sa.or_(  # Keyword can be in field1 or in field2
            sa.func.lower(models.YourModel.field1).contains(keyword.lower()),
            sa.func.lower(models.YourModel.field2).contains(keyword.lower()),
        )
    )
```